# Elasticsearch query on a specific index

Tags: syntax, indexing, elasticsearch, sense

I have already searching this since 2 days now. I use the sense chrome plugin to be able to test my queries but I don't find how to specify on which index he is supposed to search. So my queries search on all the indexes and it isn't easy to use.

I have try the following syntaxes:

```
GET _search
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
           "_index": {
              "value": "dev_events2"
           }
        }
    }

}

GET _search
{
    "_index": "dev_events2",
    "query": {
        "match_all" : {  }
    }

}

GET _search
{
    "index": "dev_events2",
    "query": {
        "match_all" : {  }
    }

}
```

Regards,

Benjamin V.

---

Edit I finally have found the answer: just add the index name into the url for the get: localhost:9201/myIndexName

Comment: you can also filter by _index : "<index name>" if your mapping for your docs has "_index" : {"enabled":true}

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html

Answer (score 38):

Heres curl example what works, and allows you to search multiple indexes:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/myindex1,myindex2/_search?q=*'
```

For single specific index:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/myindex1/_search?q=*'
```

To find find index names:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices'
```

And if you want to search all indexes:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty'
```

Answer (score 27):

```
GET index_name/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_all" : { }
    }
}
```

or specify the index type

```
GET index_name/index_type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_all" : { }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is also true for the DevTools Console when using [kibana](https://www.elastic.co/kibana) (http://localhost:5601/app/dev_tools#/console)

Answer (score 22):

You can also add the index/type to the GET/PUT/DELETE ... query:

```
GET index/type/_search
{
   "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```